# Edit SQL event properties on DBeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

When I select create a new envent in DBeaver I get the following windows:

[image]

But I can not edit any of the options on the properties.

I can change the source to:

```
CREATE EVENT test2
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO SELECT 1
```

But just before saving it the previous text appears at the begining:

[image]

And I'm not able to edit this text either.

Answer (score 1):

The probability this behavior is the bug in DBevaer. You should notify developers and create an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/). Also, you can modify your Event with [ALTER EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-event.html) statement. For example:

```
ALTER EVENT test2
ON SCHEDULE
AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
DO SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save the modified event source by simply using Ctrl-S which brings the alter dialog box in DBeaver. You press Persist and the modified source is altered in the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).